# Is there a way to wrap a Go library in .Net

Tags: .net, go, wrapper

I have seen here and there that Go is like a modern-time C/C++ (meaning: with modern syntax and memory management, but about as fast).
I'm interested in leveraging the power of such a language, to include an image processing library in our .Net application.

But that raises the problem of wrapping the Go library in a .Net shell. I have successfully wrapped a C library using C++/CLI ; is there a way to do a similar thing with Go ?

I would like to NOT use Swig, which I tried before, and is absolutely awful and doesn't work most of the time.

Comment: You can use the `cgo` tool to generate C wrapper files, compile that and build a library from it, I suppose. Haven't tried it myself. see here: http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go

Comment: Yo, I heard you liked wrappers, so I put a wrapper inside of your wrapper. Thanks, I'll take a look. (edit : I haven't tried because I'm merely at the "what's possible ?" stage)

Comment: Why Go and not C? AFAIK, the C image handling libraries tend to be faster.

Comment: Just because I heard Go was more modern than C and about as fast. I am exploring all possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible to embed Go code into a program whose main language isn't Go because Go needs a non-trivial runtime that hooks into many things. The only possible thing is to call C functions from a Go program; these functions may then in turn call Go functions. You might want to design a solution that uses some sort of inter-process communication instead where the part you want to write in Go runs in a different process.